# How to set value to a property present in application.properties for Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, application.properties, aws-secrets-manager

I have ssl enabled for my spring boot application. I am fetching the keystore password from AWS Secrets Manager through a class in my application. 
How do I refer to this password in my application.properties?

Comment: So you want to assign the keystore password value to a property (for eg. password= ) defined in your application.properties, right?

Comment: yes. This is my application.properties file

    server.port: 8443
    server.ssl.key-store: acceptance.p12
    server.ssl.key-store-password: ${password}
    server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
    server.ssl.keyAlias: acc

This password I want to fetch from the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the property value, you can set it in the environment as below:

```
String password = getPasswordFromKeyStore();
environment.setProperty("password", password);
```

So it will get assigned to property defined in application.properties file.